# how to start springboot build in tomcat as TeamCity step?

Tags: node.js, maven, tomcat, spring-boot, teamcity

I'm trying to set up TeamCity plan to run my e2e tests which is written in ReactJs. My e2e test bring up IE browser, for this purpose, I have my TeamCity Agent installed on Windows machine. The problem I'm facing currently is, I could successfully start my springboot embedded tomacat but the TeamCity step is stuck there. Anybody could suggest me how to resolve it. My TeamCity build steps are as below.

1. check out application from git and maven install all modules
2. start tomcat, I'm using this command  mvn spring-boot:run
3. start e2e tests. npm test-e2e
4. stop tomcat

But the build step is stuck on step 2. I need to find a way to start springboot tomcat in the background on Windows machine I think.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand a thing but why do you need to start Tomcat separately ? Spring Boot usualy brings Tomcat with it...Apart from that I would recommend to read the spring boot documentation cause usually running integration tests can be done easily. And what exactly do you want to test with your `npm test-e2e` ? You should test your npm module separately...

Comment: the spring boot plugin has a fork parameter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#fork - so adding a -Dfork=true to step 2 might do what you need